# How can I upload to a PPA without .changes file?

Tags: application-development, ppa, deb

So, I'm developing an app for the Ubuntu Showdown, and as quickly is still very buggy (I had problems using it), I decided to do my app *entirely* from scratch, using Python/GTK+3. I've done my app and I've just packaged it using only `fakeroot dkpg-deb --build`.

The problem is that I can't create a .source file, as I don't have a changelog file and the debian folder cannot be used in debuild, as is uncorrectly organized. The text shown by `ls -l -R`:

```
.:
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 francisco francisco    2 jul  3 17:48 compat
drwxrwxr-x 2 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 20:37 DEBIAN
drwxrwxr-x 3 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 18:36 opt
drwxrwxr-x 3 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 20:40 usr

./DEBIAN:
total 36
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco 1327 jul  3 20:26 control
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco 1329 jul  3 20:17 control~
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco   10 jul  3 20:20 postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco   10 jul  3 20:36 postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco  121 jul  3 20:35 postrm~
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco   10 jul  3 20:20 preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco   10 jul  3 20:20 prerm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco  530 jul  3 20:37 rules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco  530 jul  3 20:37 rules~

./opt:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 18:36 espectalll123

./opt/espectalll123:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 18:36 virtuam

./opt/espectalll123/virtuam:
total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 francisco francisco 12614 jun 27 13:58 assistant.glade
-rwxrwxr-x 1 francisco francisco   758 jun 30 17:53 virtuam
-rwxr-xr-x 1 francisco francisco  6285 jul  3 17:39 vui.py

./usr:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 4 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 20:46 share

./usr/share:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 20:46 applications
drwxrwxr-x 2 francisco francisco 4096 jul  3 20:40 pixmaps

./usr/share/applications:
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 francisco francisco 304 jul  3 20:43 virtuam.desktop

./usr/share/pixmaps:
total 188
-rw-r--r-- 1 francisco francisco 189478 jun 30 17:42 virtuam.svg
```

So, this is the question: can I upload my app to the PPA without the .source file? If not, how can I create it?

Comment: As you're creating a Python and GTK app, I would still recommend you to use Quickly, as it will take care of this and other issues for you. You are saying it was buggy for you, so I think it would be easier to describe exactly why Quickly wasn't working and try to solve the issues with Quickly instead.

Comment: @DavidPlanella OK, trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unluckly, there are just two ways: to package it manually (horrible, as I've seen myself) or to restart the project with another environment. I did the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    debuild -S -k<Your pgp key ID>
```

That should generate you the file you can then dput to your ppa

Comment: Please, read better! I said that "and the debian folder cannot be used in debuild"

Comment: Just trying to help mate.  No need to be rude.  Sorry I missed that comment.  If you explain this sentence better "the debian folder cannot be used in debuild, as is uncorrectly organized."  Maybe we can help to get your folder organized.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So, I've put the ls output in the question, showing which folders I have. That's because every time I try to run 'debuild’ I need to change something.